# Assigning a textbox value to a multiple table/query field values

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have a Main form in formview
and a related subform in datasheet view
asking results to the same query.

In the Main form i have a "free" textbox that is not linked to any query field.
This textbox is an "input" value that i want to use for a module/function that will assign the txtbox.value to ALL the values under a query field.
Example:

Main Form:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim txtbox As String
Dim qryField as String
Dim FieldName as String
Dim subfrm as Object

txtbox = textbox.Value
FieldName = "Data"
qryField = Me.RecordSource & "." & FieldName
subfrm = subfrmOfMain

Call AssignValueToAllFieldValues (subfrm, txtbox, qryField)
End Sub
```

In the module/function:

```
Public Sub AssignValueToAllFieldValues (Byval subfrm as Object, Byval txtbox as String, Byval qryField as String)

For each qryField.value in subfrm.qryField
  "assign txtbox.value to qryField.value"
Next
End Sub
```

This doesn't work of course..

Comment: Update field in underlying table with an UPDATE action SQL.

Comment: can you tell me how please?

Comment: Code like `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tablename SET fieldname=" & Me.textboxname & "'"`. If field is number type remove apostrophe delimiters, if it is date/time type use # delimiter. Use a WHERE clause if need to restrict records.

Comment: Rats! Missing first apostrophe after = sign in my example.

Comment: I was trying with your solution many times till at i understood that i have to use delimiters even in the WHERE clause...
Now all works well! Plz make your comments as a solution to my question so i can flag as a good solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update field in underlying table with an UPDATE action SQL. Code like:

`CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tablename SET fieldname='" & Me.textboxname & "'"`.

Remove apostrophe delimiters for number type field; for date/time type use # delimiter. Use a WHERE clause if need to restrict records. Apply delimiters as needed for parameters in WHERE clause as well.